# This task is currently locked by a running workflow and cannot be edited, when due date is passed

Tags: workflow

I am using sharepoint 2010. We have 2 differant endusers. Users from domainA and users from domainExternal. We have a document library with a workflow. This workflow is creating a task. This task has a due date of 2 weeks. When a task is overdue the external users gets an error when they try to approve the task. They got this error:

> This task is currently locked by a running workflow and cannot be
>   edited

Can I fix this?

Comment: When you say the user from "domainExternal" is trying to approve the task are you then referring to the same Task or a new one created before the old one has been completed/removed?

Answer (score 6):

I have found the solution by my self. The tasks were over due. This is a stupid error from SharePoint! Why didnt they show some warning like this: It is not possible to approve this task because it is over due. I have changed the over due date to the future and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I have a workflow with the due date setting up a daily reminder email for tasks which are not completed. I am running into the same issue listed above. I was able to change the due date to get the one approval through. However, I do not want to have to manually do this every time a task becomes overdue. Is there a way to ensure I can send daily reminders without having the task becoming blocked?